# SSRS excel export to 2 different sheets

Tags: sql-server, excel, visual-studio, reporting-services

Quick question, can we export SSRS report to 2 different excel sheets, not the 2 different tabs in same excel file. All the links i found was for 2 different tabs using page-break function but i am looking to export data from 2 data-sets to 2 different excel files.

Does anyone have any idea if that is possible to do in SSRS?

Comment: This is not possible with SSRS out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, you can only utilize multiple tabs, not multiple excel files. You would need to utilize something like SSIS to split the data into multiple files.